# How to find stat (min, max, quantile, etc) of a list without using pandas.series?

Tags: python, max, min, stat, percentile

I have a variable list of elements. I want to be able to find,

count
mean
std
min
25%
50%
75%
max
.

I know I can use pandas.Series.describe(). However, I have a restriction that I cannot use pandas for the specific problem. Is there any built in function/package that will give me the same output? Thanks.

Comment: Some of them (`count`, `min`, `max`) are built in, others you need to implement.

Comment: To implement non-built in just use lambda with```functools.reduce``` or if you want a sublist use ```filter``` and ```map```.

Comment: The numpy module has also a lot of these functions implemented, but I'm not sure whether you're allowed to use it.

Comment: Convert df column to list and apply bultin operations on them. Lists in python have enormouse builtin options you can apply on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments `count`, `min`, and `max` are all built in so you can simply call `count(your_list), max(your_list), min(your_list)`.

I would recommend using libraries such as [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) etc. if you can. If you are restricted only to the standard library you can also take a look at the [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) module.

For the others:

**Mean**

```
def mean(li):
    return sum(li) / len(li)
```

**Standard Deviation**

```
def std(li):
    mu = mean(li)
    return (sum((x-mu)**2 for x in li)/len(li)) ** 0.5
```

**Quartiles**

I will implement for any percentile, you can then use `percentile(your_list, 25)` or others as needed.

```
def percentile(li, percentile):
    n = len(li)
    idx = n * percentile / 100
    return sorted(li)[math.floor(idx)]
```

If you want to replicate Pandas [describe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.describe.html) function:

```
def describe(li):
   return f"""
   count    {len(li)}
   mean     {mean(li)}
   std      {std(li)}
   min      {min(li)}
   25%      {percentile(li, 25)}
   50%      {percentile(li, 50)}
   75%      {percentile(li, 75)}
   max      {max(li)}"""
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the best explanation and answer. Much appreciated.